# Select from one table matching criteria in another?

Tags: sql, multiple-tables

I'd really appreciate some help with an SQL query across tables. I realise this sort of thing is asked constantly, but I can't find a similar enough question to make sense of the answers.

I want to select rows from `table_A` that have a corresponding tag in `table_B`.
So, for example,  " select rows from `table_a` which are tagged 'chair' " would return `table_C`.

Also, `id` is a unique in `table_a`, and not in `table_b`.

```
table_A:             table_B:                  table_C:

id    object         id    tag                 id    object
1     lamp           1     furniture           3     stool
2     table          2     furniture           4     bench
3     stool          3     furniture
4     bench          4     furniture
                     4     chair
                     3     chair
```

Alternatively, is there a better way to organise the data?

Answer (score 148, accepted):

The simplest solution would be a *correlated sub select*:

```
select
    A.*
from
    table_A A
where
    A.id in (
        select B.id from table_B B where B.tag = 'chair'
)
```

Alternatively you could *join* the tables and filter the rows you want:

```
select
    A.*
from
    table_A A
inner join table_B B
    on A.id = B.id
where
    B.tag = 'chair'
```

You should profile both and see which is faster on your dataset.

Comment: @rjschnorenberg's suggestion is better if you have the luxury of changing the schema.  In which case you would join the three tables Items<>Item_Tags<>Tags using two INNER JOIN clauses.

Comment: Great, that's very helpful. I wasn't aware you could filter columns from the joined table like that.

Comment: Actually you can also write the join line as "inner join table_B B on A.ID = B.ID AND B.tag = 'chair'" but I prefer to put filters under WHERE.

Comment: Which of these is "better" practice and performance wise? Or is it entirely preference?

Comment: That depends very much on the tables in question.  In general, I use the first option if the select from B will produce a small number of records and the latter method if the number of B records is likely to be very high.  However, they are similar enough that's it's not much effort to try both.

Answer (score 9):

You should make tags their own table with a linking table.

```
items:
id    object
1     lamp  
2     table   
3     stool  
4     bench 

tags:
id     tag
1      furniture
2      chair

items_tags:
item_id tag_id
1       1
2       1
3       1
4       1
3       2
4       2
```

Comment: This is the better answer assuming you have control over the schema.  If you don't, consider creating a view which unions the two object tables so that you can then do what this answer suggests.

Answer (score 3):

```
select a.id, a.object
from table_A a
inner join table_B b on a.id=b.id
where b.tag = 'chair';
```

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar problem (at least I think it is similar). In one of the  replies here the solution is as follows:

```
select
    A.*
from
    table_A A
inner join table_B B
    on A.id = B.id
where
    B.tag = 'chair'
```

That WHERE clause I would like to be:

```
WHERE B.tag = A.<col_name>
```

or, in my specific case:

```
WHERE B.val BETWEEN A.val1 AND A.val2
```

More detailed:

Table A carries status information of a fleet of equipment. Each status record carries with it a start and stop time of that status. Table B carries regularly recorded, timestamped data about the equipment, which I want to extract for the duration of the period indicated in table A.