# Sql query for extracting info from one table based on other

Tags: sql

I have two tables

- `Country` with `countryid` and `countryname`
- `City` with `cityid` and `cityname`

I want to extract city names based on the `countryid` I select.

I'm very new to sql database and please help me with direct query if you can.

Thank you very much.

Comment: You need a 'countryid' field in your City table in order to do the join.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the table structure which you showed, this query is not possible. You need to add a 'country_id' to the cities table so that you know in which country is each city. Once this has been done, your query would be

```
select cities.cityname, countries.countryname
from cities inner join countries on countries.country_id = cities.country_id
order by countries.countryname, cities.cityname
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your help.... but how would the countryid in the city table fill up ??! am i suppose to put that myself ??!

Comment: @user154537: The country should be added every time that you add a city.

Comment: ok... thanks a lot for your help... it worked... can i put a where clause in the above query ?? if yes, where

Comment: @user154537: a 'where' clause would come after the 'from' clause and before the 'order' clause

Comment: @user154537: If my (or any other) answer helped you, then mark it as *the* answer. Read the FAQ if you need help doing this.

Answer (score 1):

First you should have countryid in city table as a country can have many cities. Then you can write.

```
select A.cityname from city A
where
    A.countryid in (select B.countryid from country B)
```

Please check this link if you want to find out more.

[SQL: Select from one table matching criteria in another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446778/sql-select-from-one-table-matching-criteria-in-another)

Comment: Why use a subquery instead of a simple inner join?

Comment: @No'am Newman yes, it can be solved by using inner join also. That's why I have provided link which has both the solutions. Thanx for comment.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a countryid in City table and write the following query

```
select * from city c left outer join country co on c.countryid=co.countryid;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the countryid in the city table.

```
    SELECT cityid, cityname FROM city WHERE countryid = $CounrtyID
```