# Recognise if row is Valid based on combination of conditions in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, mysql-workbench

I have table `Inbound` with ~2mil records, with the following structure

```
    Inbound table
    ID   campaign_id   Entry_status  Error_code     
    A1      1234            0            0
    B1      1234           -1           -1
    C1      4123            0           -15
    C1      4123            0            0
```

I also have a table `Rules` which is the list of all the combinations of `Entry_status` and `Error_code` which denote a **valid** entry in the `Inbound` table

```
    Rules table
    campaign_id   Entry_status  Error_code    
       1234            0            0
       4123            0           -15
```

I am trying to create a query which will allow my to list all the entries in      `Inbound`   which are valid based on the combinations      `Entry_status` & `Error_code` in `Rules`

So far I have come up with this, but it is only giving me the invalid entries, and I also suspect it to be wrong.

```
SELECT * FROM Inbound
  WHERE ID not IN (
         SELECT ID FROM Inbound JOIN Rules
         on Inbound.campaign_id= Rules.campaign_id
         where Inbound.Entry_status = Rules.ENTRY_STATUS 
          and 
          Inbound.Error_code = Rules.Error_code
 )
```

It feels like I need to nest another query to take account of the combination of the 2 columns to produce a valid entry?

Had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446778/sql-select-from-one-table-matching-criteria-in-another) and this but not help as the validation criteria is a string, rather than a combination of columns

................................

Bonus

Is it possible to add true / false field in `ìnbound` which denotes if the records are `valid` based on the rule combination in `rules`

Can I run

```
      Update Inbound I
      SET I.valid = if(**select function** = True , 1 ,0 )
```

so Inbound has the valid and invalid entries flagged, rather than just another table

---

Select function courtesy of [underscore-d](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2757035/underscore-d)

```
select distinct Inbound.*
from Inbound
inner join Rules on
Inbound.campaign_id = Rules.campaign_id
Where 
Inbound.Entry_status = Rules.Entry_status and
Inbound.Error_code = Rules.Error_code;`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select distinct Inbound.*
from Inbound
inner join Rules on
    Inbound.campaign_id = Rules.campaign_id
where -- or adding these conditions to the INNER JOIN would be the same
    Inbound.Entry_status = Rules.Entry_status and
    Inbound.Error_code = Rules.Error_code;
```

...or just change your `not in` to an `in`, since you got it completely the wrong way around! Although that nested version seems more convoluted than this.

Comment: Havn't used SQL in a while and with such big data sets (for me) concerned about the errors. Thanks!

Comment: Makes sense! Best to be cautious. Let me know if this does what you need, and if so, feel free to accept the answer :)

Comment: Would it be possible to set a boolean field in Inbound should the record be valid? Can you query true / false  off select statements?

Comment: Not familiar with MySQL specifically, but in SQL Server I would normally do this using a `merge` that lays out a source subquery applying all the necessary criteria, returns a set of matching ids and `case when` valid or invalid, and then `update`s the destination table according to these.  I believe this thread should help you write a MySQL-compatible equivalent for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262786/mysql-update-query-based-on-select-query