# How to select all orders with all items completed?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `billing_profile_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `currency` varchar(3) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `valid_until` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
)
```

And:

```
CREATE TABLE `items` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `order_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('pending','processing','completed','on-hold','cancelled'),
  `code` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `quantity` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `term` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `discounts` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `total` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL
)
```

How do I SELECT only the `orders` that have **all** of its items with status `completed`?

I tried with this:

```
SELECT o.* FROM 
FROM orders o INNER JOIN items i on o.id=i.order_id
GROUP BY o.id, i.status
HAVING i.status = 'completed'
```

But that returns only the orders that have **some** items `completed`, not **all**.

EDIT: An `order` with no `items` is also a valid result.

Comment: update you question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result  .. add also you the code you tried ..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL: Select from one table matching criteria in another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446778/sql-select-from-one-table-matching-criteria-in-another)

Comment: Thanks for your input. I edited the question with what I already tried

Comment: HAVING count(*) <> count(case when completed etc)

Comment: By the way, I ran both CREATE TABLE in MySQL 5.5 and... they fail :D You need to add PRIMARY KEY to use AUTO_INCREMENT. Just sayin'

Comment: I suspect that there are better answers out there than the selected one.

Comment: And why is that? Performance issues? @Strawberry

Comment: @Cabezota Yes - it's just a lot more query than seems strictly necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy:

```
select * from orders
  where id not in (
    select order_id from items where status <> 'completed'
  )
```

Comment: I guess 'order_id' is the FK on items. So: select order_id from items...

Comment: This also returns the orders not having any item at all. Not sure whether that's the desired behaviour

Comment: Yep, but I guess "all" is valid for zero rows too... Well, the question is not that clear.

Comment: I'm selecting this answer because it is as efficient as the others and, in my opinion, simpler

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   orders
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM   items
               WHERE  orders.id = items.order_id
                 AND  items.status = 'completed')
  AND  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   items
                   WHERE  orders.id = items.order_id
                     AND  items.status <> 'completed')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS orders;
CREATE TABLE orders (
  `id` SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
  );

INSERT INTO orders VALUES
(100),(101);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS items;

CREATE TABLE `items` (
  `id` SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  `order_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('pending','processing','completed','on-hold','cancelled')
);

INSERT INTO items VALUES
(1,100,'completed'),
(2,100,'completed'),
(3,100,'completed'),
(4,101,'completed'),
(5,101,'processing');


SELECT DISTINCT o.* 
           FROM orders o
           LEFT 
           JOIN items i 
             ON i.order_id = o.id 
            AND i.status <> 'completed' 
          WHERE i.id IS NULL;

+-----+
| id  |
+-----+
| 100 |
+-----+
```

...or...

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.* 
           FROM orders o
          WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                              FROM items i 
                             WHERE i.order_id = o.id 
                               AND i.status <> 'completed');
```

Comment: This answer seems to have equivalent cost to the previous ones posted already. If you think is cheaper, can you post the execution plan for it?

Comment: Just checked it, and it runs a full table scan on both tables. It's not faster. Here's the plan:
     id select_type table type Extra
     -- ----------- ----- ---- -----
     1  SIMPLE      o     ALL  Using temporary
     1  SIMPLE      i     ALL  Using where; Not exists; Distinct