# JOIN in two tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a two tables in MySQL. I want to create a `SELECT` that will work in the following way:

Select from the table `s_articles_supplier` those lines whose id is equal to the `active` = 1

**s_articles_supplier**:

```
id   | name
100  | Nike
101  | Adidas
```

**s_articles**:

```
supplierID | active
100        | 1
101        | 0
```

Comment: Have you tried a query yet?  If we just spoon feed you the answer, you won't learn very much :-|

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL: Select from one table matching criteria in another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446778/sql-select-from-one-table-matching-criteria-in-another)

Answer (score 0):

Use simple join with where condition

```
select a.id, name from s_articles_supplier a
inner join s_articles b on a.id=b.id
where active=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use inner join in following way for expected result

```
SELECT id, name FROM s_articles_supplier
INNER JOIN s_articles ON s_articles_supplier.id=s_articles.supplierID
WHERE s_articles.active=1
```

Hope it helps you