# SQL select number of customer orders by criteria

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm trying to get the number of customer orders from a customerOrders table where the gender is male from a customerDetails table. Could someone produce the query?

This is that i've attempted:

```
SELECT COUNT(customerOrders.orderid) 
FROM customerOrders WHERE customerDetails.gender = 1 
FROM customerDetails
```

customerDetails table:

```
name, customerID, gender    
John, 17,  1
```

customerOrders table:

```
orderID,customerID
3,  17
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select from one table matching criteria in another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446778/select-from-one-table-matching-criteria-in-another)

Comment: You have to join your two tables, but you haven't provided enough detail for us to guess what that join might look like.

Comment: I've added the tables. Do i need to join where customerID in both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a simple `JOIN` with aggregate function `COUNT()`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM customerOrders co
INNER JOIN customerDetails ON cd.customerID = co.customerID AND cd.gender = 1
```

There are two conditions in the `ON` clause of the `JOIN`:

- the first one matches records across tables based on the `customerID`
- the second one filters on male customers