# select the records only if ALL related records match

Tags: sql, sql-server

Again I am stuck with a query.
I want to select all records from table1 in which ALL related table2 records satisfy a condition.
Only when the ALL table 2 records satisfy it.

I tried this. But it's not working.

```
select m.* from table1 m
 inner join table2 I on m.Id = I.Id
where 
I.Id = ALL (select t.Id from table2 t where t.Id = I.Id and t.Status = 3)
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Did you get an error, unexpected results, something else? Can you supply sample data and expected results?

Comment: I get the wrong results

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select from one table matching criteria in another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446778/select-from-one-table-matching-criteria-in-another)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the rows from `m` where all statuses are `3` in `I`, then use `not exists`:

```
select m.* 
from table1 m
where not exists (select 1
                  from table2 I 
                  where I.Id = m.Id and I.status <> 3
                 );
```

EDIT:

Note that this matches rows where there are no matches in `table2`.  That technically meets the requirement that *all* rows have a status of `3`.  But if you want to require a row, you can add an `exists` condition:

```
select m.* 
from table1 m
where not exists (select 1
                  from table2 I 
                  where I.Id = m.Id and I.status <> 3
                 ) and
      exists (select 1
              from table2 I 
              where I.Id = m.Id and I.status = 3
             );
```

Both of these can take advantage of an index on `table2(Id, status)`.  Methods that use some form of aggregation require additional work and should be a little less performant on large data sets (particularly when there are many matches in `table2`).

Comment: negative logic?

Comment: This will also select rows from table1 where the id is not related to an id of table2.

Comment: @Henkie85 if you get rid of the join then the ids of the tables are not related.

Answer (score 0):

You could drop the join to table2 and change the all to in or exists.
 or you could add t.status = 3 to the on clause and get rid of the where clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `NOT EXISTS` to the `ON` clause:

```
select m.* 
from table1 m inner join table2 I 
on m.Id = I.Id 
and not exists (select t.Id from table2 t where t.Id = m.Id and t.Status <> 3)
```

This way you select from `table1` all the rows that are related to `table2` and the related rows all satisfy the condition that `Status = 3`.
Or, without a `join`, use in the `WHERE` clause a subquery that returns all the `Id`s of `table2` that satisfy the condition `Status = 3`:

```
select * 
from table1  
where Id in (
  select Id from table2
  group by Id
  having min(Status) = 3 and max(Status) = 3
)
```